# Data model diagram for Saleor E-Commerce?

Tags: django, django-models, e-commerce, saleor

Is there a data model diagram for Saleor E-Commerce Database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I could not find a diagram of the Product Schema prior to patrys post, so I drew one.  I did this by looking at products/models/base.py and images.py and the postgresql database tables.  Here it is:

[image: Saleor Product Data Model.png]

Answer (score 15):

I've used [django-extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graph_models.html) to generate an overview of the entire project (this is up to date as of 2017-01-25).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is really useful!

Answer (score 5):

Adding up-to date version as of 08-04-2021, its quite big - hope this helps

[image]

Which application did you use for creating these diagram? Can you share an application name and link, or download file, because it's really hard to see even zoomed! Thanks a lot!